# Invalid column name 'WEIGHT'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE SUPPLIERS
(   
    SID CHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CITY VARCHAR(20) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PARTS 
(   PART_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PART_NAME VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    COLOR VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    WEIGHT DECIMAL(6,3) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIERS_PARTS
(
    SID CHAR(8) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SUPPLIERS(SID),
    PART_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PARTS(PART_ID),
    QUANTITY INT NOT NULL
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO SUPPLIERS
VALUES(001,'GOSHO','VARNA'),
      (002, 'NANI', NULL),
      (003, 'ZAHO','PLOVDIV')

INSERT INTO PARTS
VALUES(101, 'KL','BLUE',71),
      (102,'DC', 'BLACK',45),
      (103,'FH','SD',78),
      (104,'GREEN',NULL,21)

INSERT INTO SUPPLIERS_PARTS
VALUES(001,101,50),
      (001,102,50),
      (002,102,100),
      (003,104,72)

 SELECT * FROM SUPPLIERS, PARTS, SUPPLIERS_PARTS
```

---

```
 DELETE FROM PARTS 
 WHERE WEIGHT < 50

 SELECT PART_NAME,COLOR
 FROM PARTS
```

In the last line for the 'delete' statement it underlines 'WEIGHT' and it says it's an invalid column name. why is that? Also it does not recodnisePART_NAME and COLOR from the select statement

Comment: If your error message says `WIGHT`, you are using `WIGHT` in the SQL. Change that to `WEIGHT`.

Comment: it says weight it was my tipo here.also when i addet  SELECT PART_NAME,COLOR
 FROM PARTS it does not recodnise thies columns too

Comment: Put a semicolon after `< 50`. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL server and the ';' didnt help. its like it doesnt recodnise any of the columns from the tables .

Comment: You've already been asked what DBMS that you're using (as hovering the sql tag says to add). All 3 insert statements need a `;` terminator, as well as BOTH select statements and the delete.

Comment: You have a constraint violation related to the DELETE.  Given the foreign key constraint (in `SUPPLIERS_PARTS`), you can't delete a `PARTS` row that is referenced by `SUPPLIERS_PARTS`.  See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2e4aff49e8be8c93bf5af48f1a0c8c8

Comment: WHAT underlines `WEIGHT`?  No SQL database does underlining, so you're using some kind of IDE, and that's where the idiocy is.  The statements probably execute just fine.

Comment: A red squiggly underline isn't necessarily an error - that's just "IntelliSense" not recognizing something, such as newly created tables, columns, stored procedures and user-defined functions. In SSMS select the menu option: Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache Ctrl+Shift+R.